# jQuery and jQuery Form Plugin issue placing to localStorage

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm making web app with jQuery mobile, but i got some issues getting plugins working together. I know why it's happening, but i don't manage to fix it...

So, in my web app i have selection of projects with http://andymatthews.net autoComplete plugin. After i select project, i place some data in localStorage. Project name, id etc...

Then i have some different forms after project is selected, which i submit by using [jQuery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/). I use PHP to access Mysql database so i post form information and some variables from local storage via jQuery form plugin. (I use this, becouse i also upload pictures via some of forms..)

So, problem is, that jQuery form plugin needs to be placed in $(document).ready(function(){}), and data is generated only then page loads, but i changing localStorage data each time i select new project from Autocomplete field. So i need to restart app each time i select another project from list to pass localStorage variables with form field variables to PHP. I have tryed to place jQuery form plugin to $("#page").live("pageshow", function(){}) but then plugin not working...

Here is example of problem:

By the way, sorry for my language, but anyway, thanks for any advice...

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
$('#innregulering_form').ajaxForm({
       beforeSubmit: function(){
                        $.mobile.loading('show')},
       data:         ({project_id: localStorage.project_id,
                     project_prefix : localStorage.project_prefix}),
       dataType:     'json',
       failure:      function(data) { 
                        show_message('#innregulering_header', 'Can not save!', 'red')},
       success:      function(data) {
                         load_innregulering(data.apartament_id);
                         $.mobile.loading('hide');
                         $('#pop_innregulering_file_place').html('<b>File plased at:</b>' + data.file_patch + '</br><b>File name is: </b>' + data.file_name + '</br><b>File size is: </b>' + data.file_size + ' KB');
                         $('#tmp_pdf_file').val(data.file_name);
                         $("#wiev_innregulering_pdf_popup").popup( "open", {transition:  "pop"})}
 });
```

});

```
$("#select_project").live("pageshow", function(event, ui) {
if (localStorage.project_search){autocompleteData = JSON.parse(localStorage.project_search);} else {autocompleteData = '';}
$("#project_search").autocomplete({
    target:         $('#suggestions'),
    source:         autocompleteData,
    link:           '#project_home?',
    minLength:      1,
    matchFromStart: false,
    callback:       function(e) {
                         var $project = $(e.currentTarget); // access the selected item
                         var project_name = $project.data('autocomplete').label;
                         var project_prefix = $project.data('autocomplete').prefix;
                         var project_id = $project.data('autocomplete').project_id;
                         localStorage.setItem('project', project_name);
                         localStorage.setItem('project_prefix', project_prefix);
                         localStorage.setItem('project_id', project_id);}
});
```

});